# uncaught in promise nested async function promise error handling

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I'm trying to implement promises and async/await in my project. I need to use fetch to post some data to server and then do other processes using javascript. but I'm confused on how I should handle the error for nested async/await promises.

the problem is that there's an error "Uncaught (in promise) stop!!" and the string "stop!!" doesn't get added into the div

here's what I tried:

```js
function tunggu(waktu) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const action = setTimeout(() => {
      const str = `${waktu.toString()} milisecond has passed<br/>`;
      resolve(str);
    }, waktu);
  })
}

const div = document.querySelector('#asd');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
    
    (async () => {
      div.innerHTML = 'start<br/>';
      const a = await tunggu(2000);
      div.innerHTML += a;
      throw('stop!!'); // it looks like this line is causing the error
      const b = await tunggu(3000);
      div.innerHTML += b;
    })();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error occurred', error)
    div.innerHTML += error
  })
```

```html
<div id="asd"></div>
```

This (also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0owyus6/28/)) is only a simplified version of my code, in my project the fetch uses the method POST, and the js processes actually have many more process in it so I used `throw` in it because the error may occur in any place.

Comment: your code is working. what is the problem?

Comment: @yehonatanyehezkel there was an error "Uncaught (in promise) stop!!" and the string "stop!!" doesn't get added to the div

Comment: @dapidmini - Please confirm that it's okay for the code to be posted **here**. (If it isn't, you'll have to delete the question.)

Comment: No idea why people were so quick to close this; the question was perfectly fine in my book and solvable: https://jsfiddle.net/we1rgsoj/ (having said that, it's probably a dupe [also, I only saw this after the 5th edit or so])

Comment: thanks for all the input guys, I think I can work on it a little more from here. 

regarding putting the code in a question, years ago I tried putting my codes (although it was quite long) in a question instead of a link and people also reprimanded me because of it and told me to use a link instead. since then I always use a link. the same thing happened just a few weeks back (about a reactjs question and I was told to create a codeSandBox instead of putting my code here). I honestly don't know which rule is the correct one anymore

Comment: It's never _"instead of"_. Remote links are good as a supplement, especially if you can get the code running on something like CodeSandbox where it won't run in the Stack Snippet but the code for your question should always be **in the question** (as text, not an image)

Comment: @dapidmini - See [the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): "Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*"* *(their emphasis)*. (Please read that entire page; v. useful.) As Phil said, it's absolutely fine to *also* provide an off-site resource if that will be helpful, but the full content of the question must be in the question itself. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there was an error "Uncaught (in promise) stop!!" and the string "stop!!" doesn't get added to the div

You broke the promise chain by introducing a stand-alone async function in the `.then()` handler (which throws, but has no `.catch()` of its own, which ultimately causes the error you see).

Instead, make the entire `.then()` handler async:

```js
function tunggu(waktu) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout((() => resolve(`${waktu.toString()} milisecond has passed`)), waktu);
  })
}

const div = document.querySelector('#asd');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(async (json) => {
    console.log(json);
    
    div.innerHTML = 'start<br/>';
    const a = await tunggu(2000);
    div.innerHTML += a + '<br/>';
    throw('stop!!');
    const b = await tunggu(3000);
    div.innerHTML += b;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error occurred', error)
    div.innerHTML += error
  })
```

```html
<div id="asd"></div>
```

Alternatively, return the promise from your async IIFE, to keep the promise chain intact:

```js
function tunggu(waktu) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout((() => resolve(`${waktu.toString()} milisecond has passed`)), waktu);
  })
}

const div = document.querySelector('#asd');

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
    
    return (async () => {
      div.innerHTML = 'start<br/>';
      const a = await tunggu(2000);
      div.innerHTML += a + '<br/>'; 
      throw('stop!!');
      const b = await tunggu(3000);
      div.innerHTML += b;
    })();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error occurred', error)
    div.innerHTML += error
  })
```

```html
<div id="asd"></div>
```

Comment: @Phil You're right, that's a copy-paste glitch. I'm removing it.